# Connecting to access 97 using php on Linux

Tags: php, linux

You clever people can probably set me straight on this without me wasting any more time trawling the internet so here goes....

Our company still uses access 97 mdb files for some legacy applications and I would love to be able to connect and interrogate these databases using php / apache running on a Linux box. Upgrading the databases is not an option so I have to use them in the current format.

So the question is, is this even possible and if so, how would I go about it?

Comment: You can convert an [Access db to MySQL](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php) if you no longer need the Access project, and only want to use PHP moving forwards. Or to answer your original question, you can [use ODBC with PHP](http://phpmaster.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/) to connect to your Access db.

Comment: PHP's ODBC driver should do it, but bear in mind the constraints of using an Access DB. If this PHP system is going to need to support multiple concurrent users, an Access DB isn't designed to be able to cope with that; there's a strong probability you'll get database corruption as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Below Code :

```
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "products\\products.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

You should enable PDO & ODBC extenstions in PHP.INI file.

Comment: Thanks people. Its given me a starter. I'm using mdbtools with unixODBC. Once the information was in the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files I was able to link to the mdb file using:

$conn=odbc_connect('dbname','','');

I think I may have uncovered a 'bug' with the odbc_exec but I will post this elsewhere. Thanks for your help and I will mark this as answered shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks people. Its given me a starter. I'm using mdbtools with unixODBC. Once the information was in the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files I was able to link to the mdb file using: $conn=odbc_connect('dbname','',''); I think I may have uncovered a 'bug' with the odbc_exec but I will post this elsewhere. Thanks for your help and I will mark this as answered shortly.